# Executing Scripts via CRON

Tags: php, jquery, cron, cpanel

I have an HTML file that fires two PHP scripts when you manually visit the page in a browser. Everything works just fine when I manually type in the URL.. I would like to know how can I run this script as a cron so that it constantly fires at a given interval?

I have tried, wget, curl thus far with no luck. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.shoutcast.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan Script">
    <!-- Current Song Played -->
    <script>
        // Get current song playing and load it into an element with an ID of songtitle
        $.SHOUTcast({
            host : 'live.soundcheck.xyz',
            port : 8000,
            interval : 5000,
        }).stats(function(){
            $('#songtitle').text(this.get('songtitle'));

            $(document).ready(function() {
              //  console.log("Document Ready!");
                var content = $('#songtitle').text();
                var music = $('#songtitle').text();
                var song = $('#songtitle').text();
                var title = $('#songtitle').text();
            //    console.log(content);

                // $.post("nowplaying.php", //Required URL of the page on server
                $.post("ignore.php", //Required URL of the page on server
                    {   // Data Sending With Request To Server
                        name:content,
                    },
                    function(response){  // Required Callback Function
                        //    alert("Response: " + response);  //  "response"  receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.

                });
                $.post("new/update.php", //Required URL of the page on server
                    {   // Data Sending With Request To Server
                        track:music,
                    },
                    function(response){  // Required Callback Function
                       // alert("Response: " + response);  //  "response"  receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
                     //  console.log(response);
                });
                /*$.post("current.php", //Required URL of the page on server
                    {   // Data Sending With Request To Server
                        current:song,
                    },
                    function(response){  // Required Callback Function
                       // alert("Response: " + response);  //  "response"  receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
                       console.log(response);
                });*/

            });

        });
    </script> 

    <style type="text/css">
        #nowplaying{
            border: solid;
            border-color: black;
            width: 750px;
            height: auto;
            padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            float: left;
        }
        #label{
            font-weight: 500;
            font-family: Kaushan Script;
            font-size: xx-large;
        }
        #songtitle{
            font-weight: 300;
            font-family: fantasy;
            font-size: medium;
        }
        ol.labels-list {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            margin-left: 1em;
            padding: 0;
            counter-reset: li-counter;
        }
        ol.labels-list > li{
            position: relative;
            margin-bottom: 1.5em;
            padding: 1.5em;
            background: #45484d; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #45484d 0%, #000000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#45484d), color-stop(100%,#000000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #45484d 0%,#000000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #45484d 0%,#000000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #45484d 0%,#000000 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(to right,  #45484d 0%,#000000 100%); /* W3C */


        }
        ol.labels-list > li:before {
            position: absolute;
            top: -0.3em;
            left: -0.5em;
            width: 1.8em;
            height: 1.2em;
            font-size: 2em;
            line-height: 1.2;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            color: #464646;
            background-color: #d0d0d0;

            transform: rotate(-20deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
            z-index: 99;
            overflow: hidden;
            content: counter(li-counter);
            counter-increment: li-counter;
        }
        .lastplayed{
            font-weight: 300;
            font-family: Kaushan Script;
            font-size: medium;
            color: white;
        }
        #imgholder{
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .text-glow{
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 4em;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            width: 1000px;
            padding-top:75px;
        }
        #nowplaying{
            text-align: center;
        }

        .text-glow:hover,
        .text-glow:focus
        .text-glow:active{
            -webkit-stroke-width: 5.3px;
            -webkit-stroke-color: #000000;
            -webkit-fill-color: #FFFFFF;
            text-shadow: 1px 0px 20px #F90;
            -webkit-transition: width 0.3s; /*Safari &amp; Chrome*/
            transition: width 0.3s;
            -moz-transition: width 0.3s; /* Firefox 4 */
            -o-transition: width 0.3s; /* Opera */

        }

        .text-glow a{

            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in; /*Safari &amp; Chrome*/
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in; /* Firefox 4 */
            -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in; /* Opera */

            text-decoration:none;
            color:#000000;
        }
        #songtitle{
            font-size: x-large;
        }
    </style>                                        
</head>
<body>

    <div id="reload"><span id="songtitle" class="now"></span></div>
    <div id="php"><?php echo date('l, F jS, Y'); ?></div>
    <div id="php2"><?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?></div>

</body>
```

Comment: its js, you need a browser for it to run. still can be done via cron but its painful - can you convert it to pure server side?

Comment: You might want to look at something like [Codeception](http://codeception.com/) and write a test for it. Codeception use phpBrowser and can handle things like javascript. Then like @Dagon said, just schedule a cron to kick off the test however often you would like.

Comment: This is really unrealistic, but you could open the page (via cron) with a text-based browser that supports modern js. elinks is the only one I know of, if compiled with spidermonkey

Answer (score -1):

in your case and if you're on a Linux server, you should put your entire html/jquery content into a .php file and save it at a location where its executable and web accessible and issue:

```
sudo crontab -e //this will open the crontab in whatever editor
```

insert the cronjob in this format

```
*/10 *  *  *  *     curl 'http://host/php-script-location/php-script.php' 
//feel free to pass in parameters.
```

make sure to adjust the time for the cron, this (*/10 *  *  *  *) needs to be adjusted in order for you to setup a correct time for the cronjob to run

use cURL, don't use wget, cURL simulates a browser like action

then issue `crontab -l` to make sure your cronjob is there. it will print out lines
showing your cronjob.

do a few tests and you should be OK.

Comment: curl will not execute the js either

Comment: try this "/usr/bin/firefox http://host/html-location/html-file.html or try NodeJS. Make sure you have firefox installed on the system. There is a way to write a cURL script that'll use Javascript but might be time consuming for you.

Comment: so how many copies of firefox will end up running on this machine?

Comment: many. if you're worried about that in the script issue kill -KILL firefox-pid after you're done. Find the firefox ps by issuing ps -e | grep "firefox". that may become an issue overtime depending on your server.

Answer (score -5):

1. open your serverterminal, type crontab -e
2. for a cronjob that's executed every minute type:

   `* * * * * php /path/to/your/File`
3. save file
4. have fun :)